# How to use relative path to files inside Angular Library?

Tags: angular, angular-library

I've created a library for theming, in which i'm changing the stylesheet path depending on the selected theme. My problem is that the path inside my library is `assets/themes`, but if I add the library to a project, that is not working anymore since it points to the project's `assets/themes` instead of the library's. Is there a way to relatively reference that path inside the library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep the relative path in **environment.ts** and then pass it to the library module using `forRoot`.

Suppose you want to use the path in `libService` or any other file as per your requirement,

Try like this:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { LibModule } from 'some-library';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        libModule.forRoot({
            environment: environment
        })
    ]
})
```

**LibModule.module.ts**

```
export class LibModule{ 
  static forRoot(config): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: LibModule,
      providers: [LibService, {provide: CONFIG, useValue: config}]
    };
  }
}
```

**libService.service :**

```
export const CONFIG = new InjectionToken<any>('config');

export class LibService{

  constructor(@Inject(CONFIG) private config:any) {
    console.log(config)
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you added `{provide: config, useValue: config}` in lib.modue? Ensure it is `config` not `CONFIG`, I edited the answer few minutes back

Comment: Actually I've declared an `InjectionToken` that I'm using for that. `export const PATH_CONFIG = new InjectionToken<string>('assets.path');`  and using it like 
`{provide: PATH_CONFIG, useValue:config}`

Comment: Oh.. Can you share it in stackbiltz, we have to check the complete scenerio

Comment: It's quite a large lib to be able to reproduce it sadly.

Comment: So, I've managed to pinpoint part of the problem.I think that somehow the service gets constructed before the config gets set. If i remove the `@Inject('PATH_CONFIG') private config:string` from the service's constructor it doesn't throw an error anymore.

Comment: If you added ` providers: [LibService, {provide: config, useValue: config}]`, this means config gets set in `LibService` at the time it is injected

Comment: Fixed it. I've edited your answer to match the working reproduction.

Comment: I think your edit is rejected by the community. You cannot just modify someone's answer. Can you add the change in the comment so that I edit the answer

Comment: In `libService`  :   `export const CONFIG = new InjectionToken<any>('config');

export class LibService{

  constructor(@Inject(CONFIG) private config:any) {
    console.log(config)
   }
}`

Comment: In `libModule`: changed the providers to `[LibService, {provide: CONFIG, useValue: config}]`